# Redirect incoming calls to a pre defined number

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to redirect incoming call to a pre defined number?

say the user wants to redirect ceratin group of numbers to another phone.

Is this possible?

Comment: If there was, it would raise some pretty serious security concerns. For example, a malignant app could redirect incoming calls so that people who think they're calling you end up at an expensive premium number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "you can't". Call forwarding is the responsibility of your phone carrier and nothing to do with Android. By the time a call has reached your phone, it is too late to forward it anywhere.